# What would be the instrument/index with the most historical data available for something similar to TLT aka a bonds fund?

Tags: bonds, mutual-funds, index-fund, historical-data, yield

I would like to have as much historical data as possible regarding a bonds fund performance similar to the iShares 20+ Year Treasury Bond ETF (TLT).

For now I have this source but it goes back to only 2002 which is the TLT date of inception.

https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/TLT?period1=0&period2=1765360589&interval=1d&events=history

Is there other any data source out there available that could provide similar data but for much more history?

Answer (score 0):

TLT is just long-dated treasuries.

You can go directly to the source and get data going back to 1990 here: https://home.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/TextView?type=daily_treasury_yield_curve&field_tdr_date_value=2022

You can also pull treasury data from FRED, for example: https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/TB3MS I could have sworn I pulled 10yr yields at some point, but I am not immediately finding it on the site.

Another stop gap is to use corporate data and extrapolate yield markup. For that you might use AGG, or better yet the index underlying the ETF. FRED also has data on 10yr corporates: https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/HQMCB10YR

In general, FRED and Yahoo Finance are great options as far as free tools go.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. Indeed, we have access to long-dated treasury yields from FRED, e.g. https://fred.stlouisfed.org/graph/?id=GS10,GS20. But how to convert raw treasury yields data to a series of "price" (or performance) for such a basket of instruments?

Comment: Are you familiar with pricing fixed income? If so, it is computationally difficult, but just go through each point and discount the cash flows. You can find the coupon rates here: https://www.treasurydirect.gov/auctions/auction-query/ to help, and you can bootstrap the treasury curve to find the zero rates if you want to be more precise.  But like I said very computationally difficult

Comment: This sounds very interesting, unfortunately I am not familiar with pricing fixed income...I understand what cash flows discounting is, but not sure if I would be able to compute it...Could you elaborate on this sentence please? I am not sure to understand : "you can bootstrap the treasury curve to find the zero rates if you want to be more precise" Thanks!

Comment: @Bruno ahh, it will be kind of difficult to explain without the necessary background, apologies. Usually bootstrapping uses the yields and prices to get the zero rate, this technique would just go in inverse. Sorry I couldn't be of more help, maybe you can pull prices from that link in my comment. But remember that bonds are priced relative to par; you can't just simply follow the price and get an idea of how buying and holding the bonds would do

Answer (score 0):

Existing vehicles will not get you way farther than 2002, ETFs only emerged at some point of time. First (equity) ETF in USA was launched 1993. Indices on other hand are around for longer and many of them have been calculated retroactively further back in time.

It could be legitimate for your use to extend the ETF data you already have with the said ETF's benchmark index Bloomberg US Treasury: 20+ Year Index  (https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/LT11TRUU:IND?sref=xec6wqBT) for which daily total return data is available since at least 02/01/1992. Not sure how to get the data in a freely accessible way though.

A similar one, S&P U.S. Treasury Bond 20+ Year Total Return Index starts on a daily basis from 12/29/1989.

If you would like to go farther back, need to sacrifice the "20+" part and daily prices. Then you would have the likes of Bloomberg US Treasury: Long Index (https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/LUTLTRUU:IND?sref=xec6wqBT) or Bloomberg US Treasury Index (https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/LUATTRUU:IND?sref=xec6wqBT), that go back till 1973 on a monthly total return basis.

As mentioned above, calculating total returns out of yields is computationally tricky. It is relatively easy to arrive at a rough estimate, but very difficult to do it right. For the latter you would need additional data next to yields for different maturities (at least duration of your index, or better yet single securities information).